Characteristic Function and Student's $t$-distribution; a Problem
I'm not sure if it is a mistake in the text or if it is actually meant to be like this, but I'm reading An Intermediate Course in Probability by Gut, and in the chapter on moment generating function (mgf)/characteristic function (cf)/etc. there's this exercise which I think is somewhat challenging. What I find confusing about this exercise is that the author doesn't list the cf of the Student's $t$-distribution at the end of the book with the other cfs of some well-known distributions, because it is too complicated. Therefore I'm not sure if this is meant to be like this, but the problem reads:

Exercise 5.2. Solve exercise 3.3 using transforms [e.g. mgfs/cfs/etc.]


Exercise 3.3 If $X\mid \Sigma^2=\lambda\in N(0,1/\lambda)$ with $\Sigma ^2\in \Gamma \left(\frac{n}{2}{,}\frac{2}{n}\right)$, show that $X\in t(n)$

Here's my attempt; denote by $\varphi_X$ the cf of $X$, then $$\varphi_X(t)=Ee^{itX}=E(E(e^{itX}\mid\Sigma^2))=Eh(\Sigma^2),$$where $h(\lambda)=\varphi_{X\mid \Sigma^2=\lambda}(t)=e^{-t^2/(2\lambda)}$, since recall the cf of $N(0,\sigma^2)$ is just $e^{-t^2\sigma^2/2}$.
Now, $$\varphi_X(t)=Ee^{-t^2/(2\Sigma^2)}=\ldots $$and I don't know how to proceed further. Any ideas on how to solve this problem? I'm not sure this is the right approach, since the cf of $X\in t(n)$ is nowhere given.

You should try to compute $E(|X|^s).$

@LetacGérard Could you elaborate how this would help solve the problem?

Elaboration below as an answer. The good tool is not the Fourier or the Laplace transform which leads here to unpleasant calculations, but the Mellin transform (which is nothing else that the Laplace transform of the logarithm of a positive rv0.

(The difficult integrals correspond to modified Bessel function of the 2nd kind. The Digital Library of Mathematical Functions (DLMF) lists a lot of such representations. )

Following your derivations, I got
$$
\varphi_X(t)=\frac{\left(n/2\right)^{n/2}}{\Gamma(n/2)}\int_0^\infty \exp\left(-\frac{n\lambda}{2}-\frac{t^2}{2\lambda}\right)\lambda^{n/2-1}\,\mathbb{d}\lambda. 
$$Substitute $u=n\lambda/2$, this becomes
$$
\varphi_X(t)=\frac1{\Gamma(n/2)}\int_0^\infty \exp\left(-u-\frac{\left(t\sqrt{n}\right)^2}{4u}\right)\frac{1}{u^{-n/2+1}}\,\mathbb{d}u. 
$$
This is in the form of an integral representation of modified Bessel function of the 2nd kind $K_{\alpha}(z)$ (Eqn 10.32.10 of DLMF). Using $K_{\alpha}(z)$, I got
$$\begin{align}
\varphi_X(t)&=\frac{2^{1-n/2}}{\Gamma(n/2)}\left({\left|t\right|\sqrt{n}}\right)^{n/2} K_{-n/2}\left(\left|t\right|\sqrt{n}\right)\\
&=\frac{2^{1-n/2}}{\Gamma(n/2)}\left({\left|t\right|\sqrt{n}}\right)^{n/2} K_{n/2}\left(\left|t\right|\sqrt{n}\right),
\end{align}
$$
where the last equality follows from $K_{\alpha}(z)=K_{-\alpha}(z)$.

Now we work on the c.f. $\varphi_T(t)$ of Student's $t(n)$ distribution. By definition, this is
$$
\varphi_T(t)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp\left(\mathrm{i}\,tx\right) f_T(x;n)\,\mathbb{d}x,  
$$where $f_T(x;n)$ is the pdf, given by
$$f_T(x;n)=\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{n+1}2\right)}{\sqrt{n\pi}\Gamma\left(\frac{n}2\right)}\frac{1}{\left(1+\frac{x^2}n\right)^{n/2+1/2}}.
$$
Replace $\exp\left(\mathrm{i}\,tx\right)$ by $\cos\left(tx\right)+\mathrm{i}\,\sin\left(tx\right)$ to get
$$
\varphi_T(t)=\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{n+1}2\right) n^{n/2}}{\sqrt{\pi}\Gamma\left(\frac{n}2\right)} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\cos\left(tx\right)+\mathbb{i}\,\sin\left(tx\right)}{\left(n+{x^2}\right)^{n/2+1/2}}\,\mathbb{d}x. 
$$
Note that the $\sin$ part is odd and contributes nothing to the integral, and we can double the $\cos$ part and integrate over $\mathbb{R}^+$. This gives
$$
\varphi_T(t)=\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{n+1}2\right) n^{n/2}}{\sqrt{\pi}\Gamma\left(\frac{n}2\right)} \cdot 2\cdot  \int_0^\infty \frac{\cos\left(tx\right)}{\left(\sqrt{n}^2+{x^2}\right)^{n/2+1/2}}\,\mathbb{d}x. 
$$
This is also in the form of an integral representation of $K_\alpha(z)$ [Eqn 10.32.11  of DLMF], leading to
$$\begin{align}
\varphi_T(t)&=\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{n+1}2\right) n^{n/2}}{\sqrt{\pi}\Gamma\left(\frac{n}2\right)} \cdot 2\cdot \frac{\sqrt{\pi}\left|t\right|^{n/2}}{\Gamma\left(\frac{n+1}2\right)\left(2\sqrt{n}\right)^{n/2}}
K_{n/2}\left(\left|t\right|\sqrt{n}\right)\\
&=\frac{2^{1-n/2}}{\Gamma(n/2)}\left({\left|t\right|\sqrt{n}}\right)^{n/2} K_{n/2}\left(\left|t\right|\sqrt{n}\right), \\
\end{align}
$$
which is identical to $\varphi_X(t)$.
This completes the verification that the Normal-Inverse Gamma mixture is marginally equivalent to the Student's $t$ distribution.

PS: I can hardly agree that deriving this cf simplifies anything, compared to working on the pdf directly.

Thanks! Sorry to bother by checking your computation, but I don't see how you got $$\varphi_X(t)=\frac{2^{1-n/2}}{\Gamma(n/2)}\left({\left|t\right|\sqrt{n}}\right)^{n/2} K_{n/2}\left(\left|t\right|\sqrt{n}\right).$$ Note that in the expression for $\varphi_X(t)$ prior to this, we don't have any factor $\left({\left|t\right|\sqrt{n}}\right)^n$ outside the integral. $K_{n/2}\left(\left|t\right|\sqrt{n}\right)$ gives us a factor $\left({\left|t\right|\sqrt{n}}\right)^{n/2}$, so we end up with $(|t|\sqrt{n})^n$ outside the integral, which wasn't there in the prior expression.

@psie $\nu$ is actually $-n/2$ rather than $n/2$. Note that $K_\alpha(z)$ is the same as $K_{-\alpha}(z)$. So this might have caused the confusion. I just edited the equations a little bit. I hope that it's clear now.

$B(a,b)=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{u^{a-1}du}{(1+u)^{a+b}}$ for $a,b>0.$ Therefore by the change of variable $u=t^2/n$ we have for $-1< s<n$
$$E(|T|^s)\equiv\int_0^{\infty}\frac{t^sdt}{(1+\frac{t^2}{n})^{(n+1)/2)}}\equiv n^{s/2}\Gamma(\frac{s+1}{2})\Gamma(\frac{n-s}{2}),$$ where the notation $f(s)\equiv g(s)$ means that $s\mapsto f(s)/g(s)$ is constant. Similarly if $\Lambda$ is Gamma$(n/2, 2/n)$  and if $X|\Lambda$ is $N(0, 1/\Lambda)$ an analogous calculation shows $E(|X|^s)=E(|T|^s)$ for $-1< s<n.$ As a consequence $|X|\sim|T|.$ Finally $X$ and $T$ are both symmetric variables (meaning $X\sim -X$ and $T\sim -T$), leading to $X\sim T.$

The Laplace transforms of $\log |X|$ and $\log |T|$ do exist on an open non empty interval, this implies $\log|X|\sim \log |T|$.

Thanks! I seemed getting an extra $n^{s/2}$ factor outside the two $\Gamma$'s?

Correct! many thanks.

Given
\begin{gather*}
    X | \Sigma^2 = \lambda \sim N(0,1/\lambda) \,,
    \\
    \Sigma^2 \sim \Gamma(\tfrac{n}{2} , \tfrac{2}{n}) \,.
\end{gather*}
The conditional pdf of $X | \Sigma^2 = \lambda$ is
$$
g(x|\lambda) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \lambda^{1/2} e^{-\lambda x^2/2} \,.
$$
Meanwhile, the marginal pdf of $\Sigma^2$ is (assuming the shape-scale parameterization of the $\Gamma$ distribution)
$$
h(\lambda) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(\tfrac{n}{2}) (\tfrac{2}{n})^{n/2}} \lambda^{n/2-1} e^{-\lambda n/2} \,.
$$
But the conditional pdf of $X | \Sigma^2 = \lambda$ is also given by
$$
g(x|\lambda) = \frac{q(x,\lambda)}{h(\lambda)} \,,
$$
where $q(x,\lambda)$ is the joint pdf of $(X,\Sigma^2)$. Therefore, the marginal pdf of $X$ is
$$
f(x) = \int q(x,\lambda) d{\lambda} = \int g(x|\lambda) h(\lambda) d{\lambda} \,,
$$
where integration is over the support of $h(\lambda)$, namely, over all $\lambda \in (0,\infty)$. Substituting in the above identities,
\begin{align*}
    f(x) & = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi} \, \Gamma(\tfrac{n}{2}) (\tfrac{2}{n})^{n/2}} \int_{0}^{\infty} \lambda^{(n+1)/2-1} e^{-\lambda(x^2+n)/2} d{\lambda}
    \\
    & = \frac{\Gamma(\tfrac{n+1}{2}) (\tfrac{2}{x^2+n})^{(n+1)/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi} \, \Gamma(\tfrac{n}{2}) (\tfrac{2}{n})^{n/2}} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\Gamma(\tfrac{n+1}{2}) (\tfrac{2}{x^2+n})^{(n+1)/2}} \lambda^{(n+1)/2-1} e^{-\lambda(x^2+n)/2} d{\lambda} \,.
\end{align*}
The integrand is precisely the pdf of a random variable with a $\Gamma(\tfrac{n+1}{2} , \tfrac{2}{x^2+n})$ distribution, integrated over its entire support. Hence, the integral is equal to 1. Thus, after a little bit of algebra,
\begin{align*}
    f(x) = \frac{\Gamma(\tfrac{n+1}{2}) (\tfrac{2}{x^2+n})^{(n+1)/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi} \, \Gamma(\tfrac{n}{2}) (\tfrac{2}{n})^{n/2}} = \frac{\Gamma(\tfrac{n+1}{2})}{\sqrt{n\pi} \, \Gamma(\tfrac{n}{2})} \left( 1 + \frac{x^2}{n} \right)^{-(n+1)/2}
\end{align*}
This is exactly the pdf of a random variable with a $t(n)$ distribution. It then follows that $X \sim t(n)$, concluding the proof.
